# Launch Voice Recorder in Windows 10 programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10

The good old "Sound Recorder" application has been replaced with Windows 10 Store App "Voice Recorder".

I want to launch "Voice Recorder" programmatically using PowerShell or C#.

What is the shell command to launch the Voice Recorder in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to launch an AppX app from the desktop is to use the shell's [`IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

```
void Main()
{
    var mgr = new ApplicationActivationManager();
    uint processId;
    var name = "Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
    mgr.ActivateApplication(name, null, ActivateOptions.None, out processId);
}

public enum ActivateOptions
{
    None = 0x00000000,  // No flags set
    DesignMode = 0x00000001,  // The application is being activated for design mode, and thus will not be able to
    // to create an immersive window. Window creation must be done by design tools which
    // load the necessary components by communicating with a designer-specified service on
    // the site chain established on the activation manager.  The splash screen normally
    // shown when an application is activated will also not appear.  Most activations
    // will not use this flag.
    NoErrorUI = 0x00000002,  // Do not show an error dialog if the app fails to activate.
    NoSplashScreen = 0x00000004,  // Do not show the splash screen when activating the app.
}

[ComImport, Guid("2e941141-7f97-4756-ba1d-9decde894a3d"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IApplicationActivationManager
{
    // Activates the specified immersive application for the "Launch" contract, passing the provided arguments
    // string into the application.  Callers can obtain the process Id of the application instance fulfilling this contract.
    IntPtr ActivateApplication([In] String appUserModelId, [In] String arguments, [In] ActivateOptions options, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
    IntPtr ActivateForFile([In] String appUserModelId, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface, IidParameterIndex = 2)] /*IShellItemArray* */ IShellItemArray itemArray, [In] String verb, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
    IntPtr ActivateForProtocol([In] String appUserModelId, [In] IntPtr /* IShellItemArray* */itemArray, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
}

[ComImport, Guid("45BA127D-10A8-46EA-8AB7-56EA9078943C")]//Application Activation Manager
class ApplicationActivationManager : IApplicationActivationManager
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)/*, PreserveSig*/]
    public extern IntPtr ActivateApplication([In] String appUserModelId, [In] String arguments, [In] ActivateOptions options, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    public extern IntPtr ActivateForFile([In] String appUserModelId, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface, IidParameterIndex = 2)]  /*IShellItemArray* */ IShellItemArray itemArray, [In] String verb, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    public extern IntPtr ActivateForProtocol([In] String appUserModelId, [In] IntPtr /* IShellItemArray* */itemArray, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
}

[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe")]
interface IShellItem
{
}

[ComImport]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("b63ea76d-1f85-456f-a19c-48159efa858b")]
interface IShellItemArray
{
}
```

[Download this code for LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/8jjolt.linq)

Comment: Thanks, will try and share feedback.  Quick question - I want the Windows Form application to run by regular user.  I hope your code will not require any Admin (elevated) permissions.

Comment: It activates the app instance for the current user. No admin prompt.

Comment: @kamleshrao Did this work for you?  If so, please upvote and accept as an answer.

Comment: Hi @kamleshrao, is there any specific reason for you to launch Voice Recorder? I'm currently working on this app, so it would help to know what scenario you're trying to solve here. Are you just trying to let the user start a recording or would you also want to get the audio file returned for use within your solution?

Comment: Sorry guys - was busy with other tasks in the project. I am yet to try the code shared by Codekaizen.  I should get some time next week to try this.

 @FilipSkakun I am trying to automate some manual test cases related to a Hardware Certification project.

Comment: @kamleshrao - you can click the "Download for LinqPad" link and test it in about 30 seconds. If you don't have LinqPad installed, you can install it for free in about another 30 seconds: http://www.linqpad.net/GetFile.aspx?LINQPad5Setup.exe

Comment: @codekaizen Thanks a lot. I tried with LINQPad and its launching the Voice Recorder.  Is it possible to first check if this Voice Recorder (Store App) is installed or not?  I want to launch it only if its installed.